# R: Bad loop code, improve the speed?

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

I created some basic code to acheive what I need, but it is terribly slow as it's bad code. The aim is to take a row from the SE column, and if it matches with the SC column, to add 1 to the counter for each 5 minute bracket it belongs to.

The code I wrote is

```
for (i in 1:(nrow(SC)))
  for(j in 1:(nrow(SE)))
    for (k in 0:5)
      if ( (SE[j,3]==SC[i,1]) & 
        (as.POSIXlt(SE[j,1])>as.POSIXlt(SC[i,4]) +k*5*60)&
        (as.POSIXlt(SE[j,1])<=as.POSIXlt(SC[i,4])+ (k+1)*5*60 ) &
        (SE[j,2]==1) )
      { SC[i,6+k]=SC[i,6+k]+1 }
```

Which is to say check every cell of SC to see if the conditions (room numbers are the same, time fits between time brackets etc).

This is incredibly inefficient as a triple loop takes forever in R. Looking for ways to replace the loops, maybe vectors or apply?

```
> SE
            UTC         pin  Room
 1  2014-12-22 10:14:34   1 Alpha
 4  2014-12-22 10:15:27   1 Alpha
 5  2014-12-22 10:16:00   1 Alpha
 8  2014-12-22 10:18:10   1 Alpha
 12 2014-12-22 10:19:06   1 Alpha
 13 2014-12-22 10:20:00   1 Alpha
 14 2014-12-22 10:08:34   1  Beta
 17 2014-12-22 10:15:29   1  Beta
 18 2014-12-22 10:16:00   1  Beta
 19 2014-12-22 10:17:00   1  Beta
 22 2014-12-22 10:18:10   1  Beta
 24 2014-12-22 10:19:00   1  Beta
 26 2014-12-22 10:19:11   1  Beta
 28 2014-12-22 10:09:34   1 Gamma
 29 2014-12-22 10:39:11   1 Gamma


 > SC
    Room Capacity Video.Conference                  ST                  ET 
 1 Alpha       16                1 2014-12-22 10:00:00 2014-12-22 10:30:00
 2 Alpha       16                1 2014-12-22 10:30:00 2014-12-22 11:00:00
 3  Beta       16                1 2014-12-22 10:00:00 2014-12-22 10:30:00
 4  Beta       16                1 2014-12-22 10:30:00 2014-12-22 11:00:00
 5 Gamma       10                0 2014-12-22 10:00:00 2014-12-22 10:30:00
 6 Gamma       10                0 2014-12-22 10:30:00 2014-12-22 11:00:00


>Desired #This is the intended output
 X  Room Capacity Vid                  ST              ET        X0.to.5.min  X5.to.10.min  X10.to.15.min  X15.to.20.min  X20.to.25.min  X25.to.30.min 
 1  Alpha       16   1 2014-12-22 10:00:00 2014-12-22 10:30:00           0            0             1             5             0            0           
 2  Alpha       16   1 2014-12-22 10:30:00 2014-12-22 11:00:00           0            0             0             0             0            0           
 3   Beta       16   1 2014-12-22 10:00:00 2014-12-22 10:30:00           0            1             0             6             0            0           
 4   Beta       16   1 2014-12-22 10:30:00 2014-12-22 11:00:00           0            0             0             0             0            0           
 5  Gamma       10   0 2014-12-22 10:00:00 2014-12-22 10:30:00           0            1             0             0             0            0          
 6  Gamma       10   0 2014-12-22 10:30:00 2014-12-22 11:00:00           0            1             0             0             0            0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can reduce the number of function calls within the for loops (particularly the `as.POSIXlt` calls )which should help a bit.  Also, the `&&` operators might go faster since the subsequent comparisons will not be evaluated after the first that condition that evaluates to false.

```
posix.SE  <- as.POSIXlt(SE[,1])
posix.SC  <- as.POSIXlt(SC[,4])

for (i in 1:(nrow(SC)))
for(j in 1:(nrow(SE)))
for (k in (0:5))
if ( (SE[j,3]==SC[i,1]) &&
    (posix.SE[j]>posix.SC[i] + k*300)&&
    (posix.SE[j]<=posix.SC[i]+ (k+1)*300 ) &&
    (SE[j,2]==1) ) {

    SC[i,6+k]=SC[i,6+k]+1 

}
```

you can also reduce the number of times that the first condition in the `if` clause is evaluated via:

```
for(val in unique(SE[,3]))
    for(i in which(SC[,1] == val))
    for(j in which(SE[,3] == val))
    for (k in (0:5))
    if ((posix.SE[j]>posix.SC[i] + k*300)&&
        (posix.SE[j]<=posix.SC[i]+ (k+1)*300 ) &&
        (SE[j,2]==1) ) {

        SC[i,6+k]=SC[i,6+k]+1 

    }
```

using 'outer' may be even more efficient as in

```
for(val in unique(SC[,1])){
    # index the relevent rows for each value in SC[,1]
    index.SC  <-  which(SC[,1] == val)
    index.SE  <-  which(SE[,3] == val & SE[,2]==1)
    MX <- outer(posix.SE[index.SE], posix.SC[index.SC],`-`)
    for (k in (0:5))
        SC[indxe.SC,6+k]  <-  apply((MX > k*300)& (MX <= (k+1)*300 ),2,sum)
}
```

[if SC[,1] is a factor you'll want to use 'levels(SC[,1]) instead of unique(SC[,1]) in the for loop...]

Comment: I read about call functions so this is the kinda of stuff I'm looking for. Given my data set is huge I'm thinking I might have to use something else quicker than R for loops

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm at the moment is running at O(n^2) which is the best you can do if you know nothing about the properties of SE and the SC columns.
If the data in either column has some specific properties then you can do some optimization. For example

Are the entries in SE unique? If so then you can remove matches in
    SC so they aren't checked again.

Are the entries in either SE or SC sorted? If so then you can use
    comparisons to short circuit the search in SC (e.g.: if SC is sorted
    in increasing order, then while checking for matches if the row I'm
    comparing against is greater than what I'm searching for then I bail
    out as there shall be no more matches)

Comment: SE is sorted numerically/alphabetically by "Room" and then within each room by ascending time. SC likewise is sorted by Room and then within that by ascending time. So is there a way to kill it first by room, and then perhaps other metrics like day?

Comment: Yeah, that would be simple. Pseudo code would look like this
`if( se_room < sc_room) break because you aren't going to find a match; else if(se_day < sc_day) break because you aren't going to find a match further'
Same principle applies.

Answer (score 0):

Taking @jthorpe's advice a little further, vectorize where possible and pull out common calculations

```
step <- 5 * 60
se <- as.POSIXlt(SE[,1]) / step
sc <- as.POSIXlt(SC[,4]) / step
k <- 0:5
```

Updating a data.frame is expensive, so create a matrix to contain the answers

```
ans <- as.matrix(SC[, 6 + 0:5])
```

rearrange the loops so that it's possible to vectorize the computation of the first and last test criteria

```
for (j in seq_along(se)[SE[,2] == 1])
    for (i in seq_along(sc)[SE[j, 3] == SC[,1]])
```

and vectorize the innermost loop

```
    {
        d <- se[j] - sc[i]
        idx <- k[(d > k) & (d <= (k + 1))] + 1
        ans[i, idx] <- ans[i, idx] + 1
    }
```

This is still a quadratic time algorithm, as @hhafez indicates, and there is likely considerable room for improvement using the properties of your data.